# Macro with arguments with default values, where default value is previous argument

Tags: system-verilog

I have a macro defined like this:

```
`define some_macro(ARG0, ARG1 = ARG0) \
  ...
```

I'd like the expansion `some_macro(2)` to expand to `some_macro(2, 2)`. It expands to `some_macro(2, ARG0)`, because in the default value specification for `ARG1` the text `ARG0` is used and not the value of the `ARG0` argument.

Is it possible to specify the default of the second argument to be the value of `ARG0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can achieve the outcome you want.   **`ifdef ARG1** case is when a single argument is supplied, and **`else** is when both are.  You can call another common macro there, I just wanted to demonstrate the trick to allow using the same macro name.

```
`define NOT_DEFINED
`define str2(ARG0, ARG1=NOT_DEFINED) \
  `ifdef ARG1 \
     `"ARG0 ARG0`" \
  `else \
     `"ARG0 ARG1`" \
  `endif

module test;

  initial begin
    $display( `str2(hello) );
    $display( `str2(hello, world) );
  end

endmodule
```

Output:
hello hello
hello world

Comment: This won't work for cases where ARG1 is not a single token, though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.   Can you give an example of where it won't work?

Comment: Actually, the code in the answer doesn't work at all.

Comment: @TudorTimi  Thanks for testing.   I found a syntax issue for using macros as string.   It has to be `", not ", corrected in the answer now.    vcs was forgiving and didn't give an error.    Now it should work for all simulators.

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected, this seems to work. Let me explain what my concern was.

Imagine I don't just want to pass `world` to `ARG1`, I want to pass `Tudor Timi`. I'd end up with code like `ifdef Tudor Timi`, which I thought is illegal. Somehow, and don't ask me how, this seems to work. I had the impression that what comes after `ifdef` is limited to only be a single token, i.e. no spaces allowed. I also tried stuff like `foo#(bar)` (which can come up when trying to use types as macro arguments) and that also works! Mind blown!

Comment: I had inherited some code that tried (and failed) to do something similar, but now I see what the difference was. For reference, this is the code: https://github.com/svunit/svmock/blob/45f8be8ecde18c034d5b5cead9749d2feabf0ddd/src/svmock_defines.svh#L5-L10. It left me with the impression that using `ifdef` like can never work. Based on your answer, I can rework that code to work as intended, by allowing the user to pass any arbitrary value to the second macro argument.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](https://www.veripool.org/papers/Preproc_Good_Evil_SNUGBos10_pres.pdf) a good summary of what you can do with SV macros.

You could mostly achieve this with two macros, like

```
`define M(A1) \
   `M2(A1, A1)

`define M2(A1, A2) \
   "A1 A2"

module m();

   initial begin
      $display("joined string %s", `M(bye));
      $finish;
   end
endmodule
```

The difference is that this would require using either M or M2 depending on the number of arguments, not just one macro for both cases.